# Recovering multiple partitions with testdisk in a multiboot configuration

Tags: testdisk, partition-recovery, boot-manager

I'm facing this kind of problem for the first time.

Two of my three partitons got corrupted. In searching for a solution, I found `testdisk`.  I've read the tutorials and feel confortable to use it, but I'm unsure about recovering  partitions in a mutiboot configuration.

Should I highlight the partition that contains boot manager too?